# How can I have the ChromeDriver path not be hardcoded?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In my selenium tests, I have the path to ChromeDriver hardcoded with

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\kday\\Desktop\\Selenium Stuff\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

However, this means that when I export the program as a runnable jar file, that the test will not work since it cannot find the hardcoded path (if it is on another computer).  Is there any way to make it so that either..

a.) - ChromeDriver is part of the jar and runs with it
b.) - I can initialize it in the code without hardcoding the value in like that

Mostly, I want all the tests to run (in IE, Chrome, FF) by just running the jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution would be to include the .exe in your jar (don't forget to include it in your buildpath). Then, in your application, you get read the content of the .exe from your jar using `getResourceAsStream("path_to_your_exe_file")`.

Then you create a copy of your exe file in a temp directory. [See Apache commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/). Using `FileUtils.copy(in, out)`.

Then you can reference your exe file using the good old `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",C:\\Users\\kday\\Desktop\\Selenium Stuff\\chromedriver.exe");`

Comment: When you say "path to .exe file" for the getResourceAsStream, do you mean the path to the JAR file?  I think i have to extract the contents from that first

Comment: When I write the command `System.out.println(ATests.class.getResourceAsStream("Atest/AMS/selenium-chrome-driver-2.0a4.jar"));` I always get null if I make it the JAR or the .exe.

Comment: I actually had to create a new JAR file with just the .exe files inside of it because the two that I downloaded did not have them inside of it.

Comment: No it doesnt, I just created a new JAR file because the original ones had no .exe in them.  Im still having the issue where the resourcestream is null

Comment: You can put your .exe file right in main/resources of your project.. no need for a 2nd jar.

Comment: If I create a folder called resources, and then move the .exe files in there, then run the command `InputStream url = ASTests.class.getResourceAsStream("resources/chromedriver.exe");` I get the value of null.  Am I making a basic error here?

Comment: If main/resources is in your build path, then you don't need to specify resources. Just ASTests.class.getResourceAsStream("chromedriver.exe"); is fine.

Comment: `InputStream url = AMSTests.class.getResourceAsStream("chromedriver.exe");` seems to still be null.  resourcesis on the build path and is linked as a source folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90475/discussion-between-pmartin8-and-user1210304).

Answer (score 2):

You can add a Chrome driver folder under the project then use

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

to return the project path and then use a relative path to find the driver.

Comment: Eventually the project is going to get exported as a runnable jar.  Would this still work once that has been done?  It is being transferred to other computers, so the paths might not be the same.

Comment: Correct but as long as the relative path between the driver files and the project folder is the same on all computers, you should be good. I use this method currently for drivers, data files, reports, and the like and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to carry the file inside your jar. You will need to copy chromedriver.exe inside the main/resources folder of your project and reference it using the class loader ie. `ClassLoader.getResource()`.

If you do so, make sure your resources folder is included in your buildpath. 
To do this in Eclipse right click on project -> properties -> Java build path

```
URL url = classLoader.getResource("chromedriver.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", url.toString());
```

I'm not sure what the url.toString() will return if the driver is located in the jar. You'll need to try it out and see for yourself.

Comment: Seems to return null when I try with ..
`java.net.URL url = AMSTests.class.getResource("/chromedriver.exe");
`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",  url.toString());

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, you can import the driver as a Jar instead of a .exe

The jar is here.
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadseleniumchromedriver20a4jar.htm

Comment: I like this.  However, once I have it added to the build path, how would I reference it with the code?  You have to call the setProperty command in order to use chromedriver.

    `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","<part I am unsure about>");`

Comment: The property is optional. See the sample test here : https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started

Comment: Well, if you remove the comment, it does indeed find the file, but it cannot execute the file from the jar file.  I get this error.

`The driver executable does not exist: C:\Users\kday\workspace\AMStest\selenium-chrome-driver-2.0a4.jar`

Comment: Can I see the stacktrace?

Comment: Nevermind, It is still saying that the setProperty section is required.

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
 at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:197)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:109)`

Character limit hits

Comment: Oh well.. NEvermind this solution it seams buggy! I'll come with something new.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [webdrivermanager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) maven dependency to download and managed binary webdrivers for Selenium:

> If you use Selenium WebDriver, you will know that in order to use some browsers such as Chrome, Firefox, Opera, PhantomJS, Microsoft Edge, or Internet Explorer, first you need to download a binary file which allows WebDriver to handle browsers. In Java, the absolute path to this binary must be set as JVM properties, as follows:
>
> System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/absolute/path/to/binary/chromedriver");
> System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/absolute/path/to/binary/geckodriver");
> System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", "/absolute/path/to/binary/operadriver");
> System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", "/absolute/path/to/binary/phantomjs");
> System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "C:/absolute/path/to/binary/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
> System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:/absolute/path/to/binary/IEDriverServer.exe");
>
> This is quite annoying since it forces you to link directly this binary file into your source code. In addition, you have to check manually when new versions of the binaries are released. WebDriverManager comes to the rescue, performing in an automated way all this dirty job for you.

This is the maven dependency what you need to add to your pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy the `chromedriver.exe` to the resources folder and use

```java
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "resources/chromedriver.exe");
```